# Block a restricted page in React-Admin application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-admin

In a React-Admin app, is there some way to prevent a user from visiting a specific?

The problem I want to address is where a user, who has access to https://example.com/regular-content/, hacks the url to directly visit https://example.com/privileged-content/.

My App.js already contains custom routes:

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin
    ...
  >
    <CustomRoutes>
      <Route path="/somepath" element={<CustomComponent />} />
    </CustomRoutes>

    {permissions === 'DEVELOPER' || permissions === 'ADMIN' ? (
      <Resource
        name="administration"
        options={{ label: 'Administration' }}
        list={Administration}
      />
    ) : null}

  </Admin>
);
```

But elsewhere in the app, let's say on that Administration list page, I have buttons that take the user to separate static pages:

```
<>
  <Button label="regular content" url="/regular-content/" />
  <Button label="privileged content" url="/privileged-content/" />
</>
```

Is there a way, say in my App.js by using custom routing, to use permissions to block the privileged content from a regular user?

Only the client side is using React-Admin. The server side is using Java.

Those content pages are actually hosted through another service as well. They aren't themselves rendered as part of my React-Admin app.

Comment: Are you running React also on the server or is this a client-side only app?

Comment: Client site only for React-Admin. The server side is Java.

Comment: In that case no, you can try making it difficult for the user to visit that page (such as, if the user goes to this page and does not have permissions, redirect them back), but ultimately, you have to do that on the server in Java to not return data for those pages and not allow any actions that should exist on those pages.